# SSJS to delete files on enhanced FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, ftp

I have a Tracking Extract which pushes the Zip file to Enhanced FTP. I want to delete these files after they have imported into a Data Extension

How can I do that? am thinking of writing an SSJS activity that can delete the files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open a support request to enable the 'Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse' Extract Type in the Data Extract Activity, which will delete the file that matches the filename that you defined in the 'File Naming Pattern' field.

Here's a screenshot of this Extract Type (and other available options).

[image: Data Extract Activity Options]

Comment: `Zip`, `Convert XML`, `Mobile Push Detail Extract Report` are also options.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why these available types are (a) [not all documented](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types.htm&type=5) and (b) only provisioned on request. I'm just working on an implementation and no extract types were available. It's a pretty useless activity without them!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it's not possible to delete files from the FTP with platform scripting.

Files in the `Export` and `Import` directories are purged after 21-30 days, if that matters.

Comment: You can also request specific retention periods for files on the Enhanced FTP via Support case.